# bash script works from command line but returns "No default controller available" when started as cgi script via apache server

Tags: bash, apache2, cgi, expect, bluetoothctl

I'm trying to execute a script on a raspberry pi to control a bluetooth device via a url cgi (apache2) script. There may be other ways to do this, but I've struggled to get php installed without bricking the OS (several hours wasted) and I'm not interested in anything complicated.

I have a working bash script that controls the bluetooth device from the raspberry pi.  However, when this same script is called via a url (i.e. /cgi-bin/example5.sh) bluetoothctl returns "No default controller available" instead.  I can run simple scripts with no problem, but somehow bluetoothctl isn't executing the same way via the url. Is there possibly an ownership or environment variable problem"  The script has 755 permissions and owned by root. Any help in debugging would be appreciated.

My script is /usr/lib/cgi-bin/example5.sh and simply calls tries to connect to the bluetooth device via bluetoothctl (real bluetooth device mac address removed because, you know, people).

```
#!/bin/bash -e
echo Content-type: text/plain
echo
bluetoothctl -- connect "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"
```

From the command line this works correctly:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/lib/cgi-bin $ ./example5.sh
Content-type: text/plain

Attempting to connect to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Connection successful
```

When I enter `http://<my local IP address>/cgi-bin/example5.sh` I get the following in the webpage.

```
No default controller available
```

Comment: `#!/bin/bash echo ./i.sh 2` is that actually what you have in  the file/. that's not a valid invocation of bash

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` when you do this, your script won't end on errors.  Use `#!/bin/bash -e` usually so that your script will "error out" rather than continuing with further commands which will probably also fail

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The first script #!/bin/bash echo ./i.sh 2  is really 3 separate lines.  I guess the post formatted it this way and I didn't catch it.  I don't know how to fix it because it looks correct when I go to edit it.

Comment: @BradPitt : fixed your `./i.sh 2` problem, but  the `example5.sh` output is an unreadable nightmare. Remove any current formatting, (or delete and repaste from your original source), then  mouse select that text, and click the `{}` tool in the Edit menu at the top of the edit window. That should format it as `code/data/output/errMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: Also, I see I easy bug. `set -- 10; echo "\$1=$1"; if [[ $1 == 1* ]]; then echo bad match ; fi`. Look at `case "$1" in 10* ) speed="0x0a 0x0b 0x79;; 0 *... ;; 1* ) .... ;; 2* ) .... ;; esac` to reduce your code's footprint. Good luck.\

Comment: Everyone, sorry for the poor formatting, but I am trying, thank you for your patience.
erik258 - thanks, I've added the -e
Cyrus/Shelter - I've tried your suggestions, but it still gives an error about formatting as code...  I've deleted most of the web output, because it's irrelevant after the "No default controller available" error.  Is it any better?

Comment: Good job improving the 'look' of your question. Much easier to read. I think this is really an `expect` problem. Adding a tag so the right people will get your question in their "feed". But you'll do well to read, review and take to heart the items on this page : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Skip the version information at the top an search for the topics labeled "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question"  You may find that 2 -3 lines of code demonstrate this problem. .Good luck.

Comment: So, I've boiled down the scripts to the bare minimum that I believe still functions.  I'm not a script expert and I've leveraged some existing code for the example5.sh script, so that's why I was verbose initially. Fundamentally, the script works when run at the command line, but doesn't when run from the webpage.  What could be the causes?  Shelter, I did read your suggested link, but nothing pops out as the culprit.  I have spent significant hours searching the web for something to no avail, thus I'm reaching out to the experts. I appreciate the help.

Comment: shelter, based on your comment on expect I made a very simple script without it and called it directly without using two scripts, but it yields the same result.  I updated the body with the scripts and results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!  It turns out the default Apache2 user www-data didn't have permission to run bluetoothctl. I added the following to /etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf

```
  <policy user="www-data">
    <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.Agent1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.GattCharacteristic1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.GattDescriptor1"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"/>
  </policy>
```

Thanks to everyone for helping out.

Comment: Well done! You can accept your own answer after 48 hrs and gain valuable reputation points! Keep posting, and keep it as simple as possible, but no less! (-;! (You might want to understand that restriction and why it is there. If this is just your home server, little risk, but if at your job and a production system, there is likely a security risk that cause Apache to "turrn it off".).